# Jena throwing ConversionException when trying to cast to OntClass

Tags: jena

I have a particular Class URI for which I am trying to get an OntClass. The model is a regular model.

I wrote some code to find out whether the right statements were in the model, and it seems that they are so I can't understand why it won't let me view this as an OntClass. (tblURI is a String passed as a method parameter)

```
Resource tblR = m.createResource(tblURI);
List<Statement> prp = tblR.listProperties().toList();
for(Statement s : prp)
    System.out.println(s);
System.out.println(tblR.canAs(OntClass.class));
OntClass tbl = tblR.as(OntClass.class);
```

This is the output:

```
[kps:datasource/EnsembleMS#translation_stable_id, http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type, http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class]
[kps:datasource/EnsembleMS#translation_stable_id, http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type, http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Class]
[kps:datasource/EnsembleMS#translation_stable_id, http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#isDefinedBy, kps:datasource/EnsembleMS]
[kps:datasource/EnsembleMS#translation_stable_id, http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label, "translation_stable_id"]
false
com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.ConversionException: Cannot convert node kps:datasource/EnsembleMS#translation_stable_id to OntClass: it does not have rdf:type owl:Class or equivalent
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.impl.OntClassImpl$1.wrap(OntClassImpl.java:81)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.EnhNode.convertTo(EnhNode.java:155)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.EnhNode.convertTo(EnhNode.java:34)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.Polymorphic.asInternal(Polymorphic.java:66)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.enhanced.EnhNode.as(EnhNode.java:110)
    at com.KPS.myApp.exampleMethod(myApp.java:123)
```

Why is it throwing an exception and how can I get an OntClass for the resource with uri tblURI?

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't say what kind of model `m` is. In particular, if `m` was created with the RDFS language profile, the `OntModel` will be looking for an `rdf:type` of `rdfs:Class`, not `owl:Class`. If that's not the issue, then a complete minimal (i.e. runnable) example would help.

By the way, there's another problem I can see: resource URI's in the model should be in absolute form, not abbreviated form. The fact that you've got q-name URI's in your model, like `kps:datasource/EnsembleMS#translation_stable_id`, suggest that something is going wrong with your prefix handling. That won't by itself cause the problem you've reported, but it's a red flag to investigate.

**Update**

Responding to questions:

- yes, you need to be using an OntModel, otherwise it's not possible for the `OntClass` to know which langauge profile to use. Either create the model as `OntModel` in the first place:

  ```
  OntModel m = modelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM );
  ```

  or wrap your plain model as an `OntModel`:

  ```
  OntModel om = modelFactory.createOntologyModel( OntModelSpec.OWM_MEM, m );
  ```

  Of course, you many use any of the model specifications, as you please, `OWL_MEM` is just one option.
- `createResource` will not expand prefixes for you. So, you should expand them yourself before creating the resource:

  ```
  m.createResource( m.expandPrefix( "foo:bar" ) );
  ```

  Of course, this requires the prefix `"foo"` to be registered as a prefix. This happens automatically if you read an RDF document that defines the prefix in its syntax, but otherwise can be done manually with [`setNsPrefix`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/shared/PrefixMapping.html#setNsPrefix%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: As I state in the first line of my question m is a regular model, i.e. not an OntModel. Does m need to be an OntModel to get an OntClass? If so, what's the best way to convert a Model to an OntModel?

Comment: Regarding prefixes, is it ever ok to supply a prefixed uri as a parameter to m.createResource()?

Comment: In my case I had an RDFS model (using OntModelSpec.RDFS_MEM).  Thanks to this answer I realized that rdfs:Class relationships were not explicit in my model and so I needed to use OntModelSpec.RDFS_MEM_RDFS_INF so that Jena could infer the resource was an rdfs:Class from the existing subClassOf relationships.